# Two-factor authentication must be turned on for your Apple ID

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to signin on Xcode I get the following error message :

> "Two-factor authentication must be turned on for your Apple ID. After
>   you turn it on, signing in to your developer account will require both
>   your password and access to your trusted devices or trusted phone
>   number."

[image]

**What I tried :**

to restart xcode : KO

to restart the user session : KO

Here is the 2 factors identification on my Mac :

[image]

and here is from : [Account Manage](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Two-step verification and Two-factor authentication are two different things. Please read https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT207198

Comment: thanks, so what could be the problem?

Comment: Your account shows *Two-step verification*. Try to change that.

Comment: yeath thanks it's what I'm trying to do, but I can only desactivate 2-step verification, I cannot enable there 2-steps auth.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue just today. Apple has made a recent change in XCode that requires two factor authentication.

In my case, I used one of my spare testing iPhones to sign in with the Apple ID I'm using in XCode. Then I went to Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> iCloud -> [my iCloudID ID (first item on the iCloud screen)] -> Password & Security -> Two-Factor Authentication -> On. It will prompt you to answer security questions and perform other verifications. Then go back to XCode and sign in again.

Comment: thank you, it's what I found also yesterday, that worked also for me.